# Using GetOleDbSchemaTable to get Excel column names when first row is blank

Tags: excel

I have written a C# app that reads Excel files and imports the data into SQL Server.  The first row of the files contain the column names.  I have been using GetOleDbSchemaTable to get the coloumn names.  This has worked just fine.

I have now run into some Excel files where the first row is blank and the second row contains the column names.  I don't want to have to hand edit the files to remove the blank row before using them.

Is there a way for GetOleDbSchemaTable to skip the first row and look at the second row for the column names?  Any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

By coincidence I put the following comment in different question

> As far as I remember the header of the table must be in the first row, [..]

I believe it is still valid - I remember that I used to have this problem and I ended it up with removing offending row via code.